# steel toe GRIP Kodiak work boot

Tags: adjectives

I was watching The Cable Guy and came across a confusing [sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAcyxfBjDD4) of nouns:
''It's a kick in the face on a Saturday night with a **steel toe grip Kodiak work boot**.''

Could you explain me why there's *grip* in the sequence, not just ''steel toe Kodiak...''

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems "_Kodiak work boot_" is a type of boot. "_steel toe_" refers to toe protection (probably a steel nose). Finally, the "grip" is, I assume, an adjective referring to the boot, so it is not just a boot, but it has added grip.

Comment: a little googling and it should be apparent.

Comment: Work boots often have very substantial 'treads' or 'grips' so that they are non-slip on oily surfaces.

Comment: So it's like cleats, right?

Comment: Sorry but since you asked no, it's not really like cleats. What, to you, is a "cleat", please?